# Coalesce several commits on a branch without merge conflict issues

Tags: git, git-rebase

On my working branch, I do the following:

```
git reset –hard mybranch-start-commit 
git checkout mybranch-end-commit .      // files only of the latest commit
git add -a 
git commit -m”New Message intermediate commits discarded”
```

Voila, we have connected the latest commit to the start commit of the branch and there are no merge conflict issues!

While this is the solution I reached in my learning practice, is there a better, more standard way to achieve this?

Comment: I feel like if you're following "proper" git flow you wouldn't run into this type of issue (but, as we know, the real world is not so perfect). However, if it does come to that point, I'm not sure there's a "best" way to fix it. It's just better not to screw it up in the first place. I think you'll find that this question is very broad.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a better, more standard way to achieve this?

Yes: a mixed `git reset` (which is `git reset` by default) allows you to avoid the checkout state:

```
 git reset mybranch-end-commit
 git add -A
 git commit -m ”New Message intermediate commits discarded”
```

It will reset HEAD and index to `mybranch-end-commit`.
You can no add and commit.